# PHP/Apache cant Download large files

Tags: php, apache

I am trying to download a file which is 2GB using PHP and Apache2.

There seems to be a cache limit of 1.2G regardless of what I change.

here is a copy of my php.ini file : http://pastebin.com/n94GuzBr

I changed all the setting I though were important,

```
realpath_cache_size = 10G
max_execution_time = 18000
max_input_time = 10000
memory_limit = 10G
post_max_size = 10G
upload_max_filesize = 10G
```

I am using monsta ftp as a apache web server to download the files.

Comment: Have you set the PHP `upload_max_size` variable?

Comment: How are you doing the download in PHP code, are you using PHP curl?

Comment: there is not upload_max_size variable in php.ini ? the max upload is 10G *verified) and the php code is provided by monsta ftp : http://www.monstaftp.com/